# Tag question of "must"; how to determine?

Tags: tag-questions

> It must be her car, isn't it?
>
> It must be her car, right?
>
> You must be tired, aren't you?

Why it can't be expressed:

> It must be her car, mustn't it?
>
> You must be tired, mustn't you?

Note:

> Q:Is it her car?
>
> A:Yes, it must be her car.
>
> Possible tag question: It must be her car, isn't it?

Is it possible to ask: Must it be her car? (I've never used it though).

Do native speakers really avoid using tag question of "must"?

Comment: Wait, why can't *mustn't it* be used?

Comment: That's what I've usually heard @DamkerngT.  Also, **You must be tired, aren't you?** So, how to determine?

Comment: Are you learning American English or British English?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Swan, 1986]:

> 1. If the main clause has an auxiliary verb (including a 'modal'
>      auxiliary verb like can, must), the question tag has the same
>      auxiliary.
> 2. If the main clause has be, this is also used in the question tag.
> 3. If the main clause does not have an auxiliary verb (or be), do is used
>      in the question-tag.

Your example matches 1, so `It must be her car, mustn't it?` is correct.

Comment: No, the OP's example matches 1, not 2. _It must be your car, mustn't it?_ is what I would say.

Comment: @ColinFine You're right; updated my answer. Swan's 3rd edition is bit clearer about be: If the main sentence has an auxiliary verb (or non-auxiliary be), this is repeated in the question tag.

Answer (score 1):

> It must be her car, isn't it?

After a careful investigation I found the following.
"The sentence is correct because *must* is used with tbe idea of deduction." I found this explanation which can tell you why it is used like this. It was also mentioned that such structures are popular in Chinese tests. I think it should be *mustn't it?* Though I believe the question is rhetorical. People say there's no need to ask for confirmation, because you are sure, so you can just say *It must be her car.* Or *It must be her car, right?*

> I must do my homework , mustn't I?

*Must* is used to express obligation.

We can also use *don't you think?* when asking someone's opinion. Other variants are met in informal English *yes,no,right*.

> It must be her car, right? It must be her car, yes? It must be her car, don't you think?

Comment: Q:Is it her car?

A:Yes, it must be her car.

Possible tag question: It must be her car, isn't it?
Is it possible to ask: Must it be her car? (I've never used it though).

Comment: *Is tnis her car?*.is the most appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make it too obvious for you.

when you use "must" for obligation, the tag must be "mustn't/needn't"

when you use "must" for deduction , the tag can be "mustn't"

OR we can rely on the main verb as if it were without a modal.

NOTICE:

1- you must study hard, mustn't you?  [obligation]

2- you must be the nicest one here, mustn't/aren't you? [deduction]

3- you must have played a lot, mustn't/didn't you ? [deduction]

That is the most beneficial short answer you will ever get.